# Winform app using LocalDB fail to run on customer's machine after deploy

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-express, localdb

I am using VS 2013.

I created a Winforms application using LocalDB, deployed it on a customer machine target: Win 7 32bit, .NET framework 4.0.3, they **installed** the **SQL Server LocalDB Express**.

This it my app connection string

```
<add name="QuanLyKhoContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Kho.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

They get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

But the soft run properly in my machine, I can't find out what parts are missing?

Comment: My bet is they lack the update 4.0.2 to .NET 4. The safest approach would be to get them to upgrade to .NET 4.5. Also make sure they installed LocalDB version of SQL Express, and not teh regular, service-based version.

Comment: I have the exact same problem happening here, have you finally fixed the problem?